# angularjs auto populate prevent Edit

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, auto-populate

In the below link

https://plnkr.co/edit/pThmY2vMX4XmF1YGEnki?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('search', ['ui.bootstrap']);  
      app.controller('SearchController', ['$window', '$http','$scope', function ($window, $http,$scope){                     
          $scope.selected="";
            $scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 
            'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 
            'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 
            'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 
            'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 
            'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 
            'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Dakota', 
            'North Carolina', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 
            'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 
            'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 
            'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];

    }]);
```

Any idea how to prevent user from editing the text box content ?.

Example : When user types 'a'  and selects 'Alabama' , I would like to prevent user from editing the textbox and change state name to 'Alaba'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-disable` directive and set it to true when the user clicks on the name, check - [ng-disable docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled).